# Jmeter: How to use ArrayList in Jmeter, Beanshell Sampler?

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, blazemeter

How to use Array list in Beanshell Sampler-Jmeter?

Comment: Can you please invest into formatting your question so that it's readable? For example what is `rs.fetchAns("1")` - we don't have your source code so we don't know what that code meansor what it returns. Then `return type is string. ` - is it an exception you are getting or what?

Comment: Question was corrected........@Kiril

Answer (score 8):

Just like in [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), i.e. the following code:

```
ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
myList.add("something");
myList.add("something else");

for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
  log.info(myList.get(i));
}
```

Will print `myList` contents to *jmeter.log* file:

[image: Beanshell ArrayList]

---

Remember that Beanshell doesn't support [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html) so avoid using diamond operators elsewise you'll get errors. If there is no particular reason for sticking to Beanshell I would suggest considering switching to [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language - see [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) guide for explanation, benchmarks and scripting best practices.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. I was was using the Generics <>Angle Brackets and was getting error. Thanks for mentioning those, to avoid using in Jmeter Beanshell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use arraylist easily in beenshell. it is same as Java so import a package for `ArrayList` and then create `ArrayList` object.

```
//importing arraylist package from java
import java.util.ArrayList;

//creating arraylist object
ArrayList lines = new ArrayList();
```